# cut in percentage a vector time in several vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, time

I have a vector time like

```
time = [0:3500]*(1/1000);
```

And I would like to cut it into several vectors every 10%

so I compute ten percent of the entire time vector

```
ten_percent_of_time_vector = time*10/100
```

but i have some difficulties to applied the stockage of all vectors 10% per 10%

Comment: You computed the 10% of the values of the vector... You want to split and create 10 vectors of different sizes containing the values? Or in other words, do you want to count the histogram of the vector (`histcounts()`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split your vector into 10 vectors, each about 10% of the total vector you can split it like this.

```
N=10;
splits = round(linspace(1,length(time),N+1));
t={};
for ct = 1:length(splits)-1
    t{ct} = time(splits(ct):splits(ct+1));
end
```